# PHP Not running on submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a login system, and I have used similar code to this on other sites, but it just doesn't seem to be submitting for me? No errors, the page just stays exactly the same. Anyone got any ideas

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $raw = $_POST["password"]; 
    $hash = md5($raw);


    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}


        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","bans","(My Password Here)","bans");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Error ";

}

    $check = mysqli_query("$con, SELECT hash FROM panel WHERE user = '$user'");

    if ($hash == $check) {
      $insert = mysqli_query("$con, INSERT INTO panel (online, ip)
      VALUES ('1', '$ip')");

  } else {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">You are not staff/have entered incorrect information!</div>';

  }
}

?>
```

Comment: `SELECT hash FROM panel WHERE user = '$user'` ... dangerous

Comment: One thing is that you have accidentally put your `$con` inside of the SQL-queries, they should be the first parameter of the query. Or be called in this manner `$con->query("SELECT hash FROM panel WHERE user = '$user'");`, and you should look up parameterizing your queries, to prevent SQL-injections.

Comment: you have any input named `submit` in your form ?

Comment: Form here - http://pastebin.com/EC11n0H6

Comment: Not to answer your question, but what if someone entered something like `1' OR '1'='1`. SQL Injection - http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I also  need to look into SQL injections. As you can more than likely tell, I am pretty new to PHP

Comment: better use <input type="submit"> or <button type="submit"> as button with type "button" is usually used for client side processing. dont know if it send post result on server side.

Comment: *Sighs* You were right, Bajon Kovacevic, thank you.

Comment: np, i am glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))` Maybe it was a button that you dont have now. Try `if(isset($_POST["user"]))` :)

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
$check = mysqli_query("$con, SELECT hash FROM panel WHERE user = '$user'");
```

should be more like

```
$check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT hash FROM panel WHERE user = '$user'");
```

BTW you're wide open into [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: $con if inserted in quotes will become a string. Use it without quotes.